# PrimeNG Datatable with row exansion call new service and display data in a row Angular 5

Tags: html, css, angular, primeng, primeng-datatable

I am trying to add extra array of the object to the PrimeNG expandable row but I am kind of new to PrimeNG so not sure where to proceed for this issue.

Desired Behaviour:

Basically I would like to call the extra service onclick of the row and want to fetch new array of objects and display extra details in the expandable row.

for example:

click of first row should trigger service to fetch the first car owner name and surname and display the data in expandable row.

[image]

I have tried following [stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-egdbmq)

Answer (score 2):

Your data structure between your car and your owner should be linked in a single object for optimzation.

You can retrieve the owner information by filtering through the *vin* property :

```
this.carownerData.filter(c => c.vin == car.vin)[0]
```

Anyway, because in your template, you defined `let-carownerData`, you should call `showCar(carownerData)` instead of `showCar(car)`.

See working [Stackblitz](https://stackblitz.com/edit/angular-xmh7on?file=src/app/app.component.ts)

Comment: is there any way to get row-object onclick?

Comment: On click on the arrow or the line ?

Comment: Ok but when you click on the arrow OR the line ?